How to display Microsoft Graph DriveItems with a Spectre.Console Tree using a Delta Response?
I am writing a program that should Migrate files from a specific drive in Sharepoint to another. Before it is said, when you see my code, I know there are better ways to do this now, but due to certain circumstances, here I am. I am also fairly new at C# - most of my programming has been done in C++, Rust, and Python.
I'm using the Spectre.Console Nu-Get Package to make a small GUI, so there are some better visuals, particularly when trying to display a Folder or Document library. However, showing it in the right order has been an issue. Now, I know this is a classic case for recursion - what a better opportunity, no? Maybe.
I am using a DeltaGetResponse of the Document Library to make the Tree and I think this is likely an issue if only just due to the way it hands over the List of the library. I have begun this as an iterative process so far, and that's probably where all my marbles got lost - rolling on the floor to panic while trying to figure out where I am in it all.
Here is my egregious-looking function so far. I am highly aware that it is way too busy and complex, not to mention wrong.
        private void getDisplayTree(string documentLibrary, DeltaGetResponse deltaResponse)
        {
            // Setup initial Tree
            var root = new Tree($"{documentLibrary}").Style("white on red").Guide(TreeGuide.Line);
            // Get total count of folder and files in Library
            var totalCount = deltaResponse.Value.Count;

            // Work with just the list of DriveItems
            var totalFiles = deltaResponse.Value;

            // Initialize to false and zero
            bool hasChildren = false;
            bool isAFile = false;
            bool isAFolder = false;
            int childCount = 0;

            // Initialize nodes
            TreeNode rootFolder = null;
            TreeNode parentFolders = null;
            TreeNode subFolders = null;
            
            // Go through each driveItem and skip root
            for (int i = 1; i < totalCount; i++)
            {
                // Check if driveItem has children -- indicating a folder
                hasChildren = thereAreChildren(totalFiles[i]);

                // If not,
                if (!hasChildren)
                {
                    // Add node
                    rootFolder = root.AddNode(totalFiles[i].Name);
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Get child count
                    childCount = (int)getChildCount(totalFiles, i);
                    // Add node
                    rootFolder = root.AddNode(totalFiles[i].Name);
                }
                
                // Continue to deal with folders or files
                for (int j = 1; j <= childCount; j++)
                {

                    // Check if this is a file or folder
                    isAFile = checkForFile(totalFiles[i+j]);  
                    isAFolder = checkForFolder(totalFiles[i+j]);

                    // Want the child count again to see if there are more indicating that it is a folder again
                    var nextChildCount = getChildCount(totalFiles, i + j);

                    // If it is a Folder .. 
                    if (isAFolder)
                    {
                        // keep checking for children
                        if (nextChildCount != null)
                        {
                            // Add folder node
                            parentFolders = rootFolder.AddNode(totalFiles[i + j].Name);
                            // If child count for next driveItem was files then add them 
                            if (checkForFile(totalFiles,i + j)) 
                            {
                                for (int k = 1; k <= nextChildCount; k++)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Increment i when looking into deeper files{i}");
                                    subFolders = parentFolders.AddNode(totalFiles[i + j + k].Name);
                                }
                            }  
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            parentFolders = rootFolder.AddNode(totalFiles[i + j].Name);
                            //continue;
                        }
                    }
                    // If it is a File ...
                    else if (isAFile)
                    {   
                        if(nextChildCount != null) {
                            // Just add them
                            for (int k = 1; k <= nextChildCount; k++)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Increment i when looking into files not as deep {i}");
                                subFolders = parentFolders.AddNode(totalFiles[i + j + k].Name);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            subFolders = parentFolders.AddNode(totalFiles[i + j].Name);
                            continue;
                        }
                        
                    }
                    // Skip child count for next iteration
                    i += (int)nextChildCount;
                }
            }
            // Render Display
            AnsiConsole.Write(root);
        }

This is currently what my output looks like now: Output of DisplayTree
And here is a look at some of my helper functions:
 private int? getChildCount(List<DriveItem> driveItems, int item)
 {
     var count = driveItems[item].Folder?.ChildCount;
     return count;
 }

 private bool thereAreChildren(DriveItem driveItem)
 {
     return driveItem.Folder?.ChildCount != null;
 }

 private bool checkForFile(DriveItem driveItem)
 {
     return driveItem?.File != null;
 }

 private bool checkForFile(List<DriveItem> driveItems, int index)
 {
     return driveItems[index].File != null;   
 }

 private bool checkForFolder(DriveItem driveItem)
 {
     return driveItem?.Folder != null;
 }

Some of them are redundant right now just putting them out there.
This is the way the Library Display is supposed to look:

General
Source Folder

Source1

test1.docx
test2.docx
test3.docx


Source2

test4.docx
test5.docx
test6.docx


Source3

test7.docx
test8.docx
test9.docx




Destination Folder

Dest1
Dest2
Dest3



The DeltaGetResponse basically puts these in a List in this exact order the way it should be but I cannot seem to get past this hump of having to make things harder for myself than they actually probably are.
And advice and suggestions would be very welcomed.
